# How to set up openMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I would like to test openMP with C on Windows 7 with Eclipse IDE. I can't find anywhere some specific steps to follow to set up openMP. Can you help me?

Comment: Does this page help?  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/Enabling-OpenMP.html#Enabling-OpenMP  Basically you add -fopenmp as compiler flag, and add sprincle `#pragma omp whatever` into your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse you need to set up the following parameters in your project configuration:

```
C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Includes: add gomp 

C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Miscellaneous -> Other Flags:  add -fopenmp
```

You need also to install openmp binaries for MinGW:

[TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download)

Comment: So does this mean i don't have to download/install anything?

Comment: I think you need to install TDM-GCC because as far as I know the standard MinGW did not support openmp.

Comment: Can you please give me some direct directions because i seems that I messed up everything.

Comment: can you tell me what you have messed up?

Comment: I installed the TDM-GCC and now I wanted to include gomp and -fopenmp but I can't find anything in those sections. Maybe I got it wrong.

Comment: have you the the C++ version of eclipse?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't done much with OpenMP but here is what I found from trying it myself.

OpenMP allows you to tell the compiler that things should run in parallel. Here is an example that counts to 10000000000:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long result = 0;
    long i;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: result)
    for (i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
        result++;
    }
    printf("%li\n", result);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This will compile like a normal C program:

```
$ gcc -o OpenMPTest main.c
```

It runs in 30 seconds on my machine:

```
$ time ./OpenMPTest
10000000000

real 0m30.674s
user 0m30.628s
sys 0m0.014s
```

Adding the `-fopenmp` option to gcc enables OpenMP support. That is all you need to have the loop run in multiple threads.

```
$ gcc -o OpenMPTest main.c -fopenmp
```

This halves the running time to 15 seconds on a dual core system:

```
$ time ./OpenMPTest
10000000000

real 0m15.840s
user 0m30.123s
sys 0m0.037s
```

Here is a brief description of what that `#pragma` line does:

```
#pragma omp
```

This is a prefix for openmp commands.

```
parallel
```

Tells the compiler that the next statement should run in parallel.

```
for reduction(+: result)
```

Combines all values of `result` variable from the parallel loops into one value by addition. Removing this results in the final number printed out being incorrect.

I know you are using eclipse but the MSDN docs are quite good for describing OpenMP:
[OpenMP in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)